# How can I send an "non-protected" broadcast from a system service when I don't care about security?

Tags: android

I have an Android Service running in Foreground mode.
This service is running using the `sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` and all is good...this runs fine.

I also have several other user space applications that I want to send custom broadcasts to. These other applications register their own "broadcast action" with my Service that they wish to receive back in their own BrodcastReceivers when something happens.  My Android system Service doesn't know these broadcast actions yet, the applications choose these themselves.

My problem is, whenever this Service sends a message, I get something like:

```
Sending non-protected broadcast CUSTOMER_CHAT_MESSAGE from system
```

How can my service "sendBroadcast()" and indicate that I know the CUSTOMER_CHAT_MESSAGE is Unprotected, and that I don't care!

I've read all the "fixes" here, which are some variation on adding:

```
<protected-broadcast android:name="CUSTOMER_CHAT_MESSAGE" />
```

I've also read some docs explaining *why* protected broadcasts are implemented...this feature blocks other user apps from sending messages that *spoof* a system broadcast.  The "protected-broadcast" flag in the client app specifies that it should only trust *real* system broadcasts.

How can I tell the system, either on the sending side (in my Service's 'sendBroadcast()') or on the receiving side (the non-system applications) that I don't care about the security and the source of the message doesn't matter!

I'm looking for a way to have a Service running with "android.uid.system" send broadcasts that are **not** protected.

Comment: "How can my service "sendBroadcast()" and indicate that I know the CUSTOMER_CHAT_MESSAGE is Unprotected, and that I don't care!" -- it seems like it is already doing that. If your concern is that your receivers are not getting the broadcast, that's because implicit broadcasts are generally banned on modern versions of Android.

Comment: I actually **am** sending explicit broadcasts using the ComponentName of the BroadcastReceiver, so the messages are being targeted directly to the desired component. They actually **are** getting through to the Receiver too.

This issue is the ERROR message in Logcat from the Activity Manager regarding the "non-protected broadcast".  I work in a "zero error message" environment, and  regardless of the BroadcastReceiver actually getting the message, there will be questions and complaints from the other devs.  I'd like to make sure that message goes away to avoid the noise from them.

Comment: "These other applications register their own "broadcast action" with my Service that they wish to receive back in their own BrodcastReceivers when something happens" -- shouldn't that be via a `PendingIntent`? The vibe I'm getting is that you're having those other applications pass a bare `String` for an action, and that's the broadcast that you're sending. Pretty much everything else in the framework would use a `PendingIntent` (notifications, app widgets, `LocationManager`, etc.). In addition to better fidelity with existing AOSP practices, you probably get rid of this error message.